# Filtering a DISTINCTCOUNT in DAX

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have what I thought was a simple task: create a Measure that returns the distinct count of a field for all records that meet a specific filter condition, in this case a date filter. I came up with the following:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ExitFilter[Dim_Client_ID]),ExitFilter[ExitDate]<1/1/2014)
```

and the result was (blank) so I tried:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ExitFilter[Dim_Client_ID]),FILTER(ExitFilter,ExitFilter[ExitDate]<1/1/2014))
```

and the result was still (blank) so I tried:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(ExitFilter[Dim_Client_ID])),FILTER(ExitFilter,ExitFilter[ExitDate]<1/1/2014))
```

and the result was still (blank). What am I missing? And what does (blank) signify?

If it's not clear 'ExitFilter' is a table, [Dim_Client_Id] is a column, and [ExitDate] is a date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, think your second attempt is 'right' but you need to be careful about how you are expressing the date.

Later versions PowerPivot are a little bit funny about this and while "01/01/2014" *should* work I don't think it will.

Instead try replacing 01/01/2014 with 41640 - this is is the underlying date value, its hacky but then so is any kind of hard coded date :-)

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Actually with your fix all three expressions work! And yes, a bit hacky, but I often use PowerPivot to verify work I do in SQL by double-checking rowcounts, aggregations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tom, comparing dates is from my experience best done with simple [Date function](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/679.powerpivot-dax-date-and-time-functions.aspx#date).

So if you update your formula to something like this:

```
=CALCULATE([Your Measure], Table[DateColumn]>DATE(2014,1,1))
```

You will get what you need with easy-to-read code. Also, for any *advanced time-based calculations*, the best way to go is creating [dates table](https://store.office.com/create-time-dimension-WA103994479.aspx?assetid=WA103994479) and using [Time Intelligence](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/time-intelligence-in-power-pivot-in-excel-2013-HA104146216.aspx) module of PowerPivot.